# Setting parameter as results of column

Tags: sql, function, parameters

I am creating a query that uses a function (usr.udf_overpunch) to convert special characters into numeric values.  How do I set the results of col4 as the parameter @incomming which is used for input data in the function?

```
declare @incomming nvarchar(15)
drop table #tempgb
SELECT *
into #tempgb
  FROM [AdhocTeamC].[dbo].[R0530135.RPT.SPON_INVOICE]
where substring(col1, 1,5) = 'TPAMT'

select col1,
substring(col1, 1,5) as col2,
substring(col1, 38,5) as col3,
@incomming = substring(col1, 78,14) as col4,
[usr].[Udf_OverPunch] (@incomming) as Overpunch
from #tempgb
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What's the issue you're encountering?

Comment: The problem with the code above is a syntax error from the line, [usr].[Udf_OverPunch] (@incomming) as Overpunch.  

What I am trying to do is run a function against the result set of col4.  This function accepts input as @incomming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix assignment (`@incomming = ...`) with a regular `SELECT`.  It looks like you're trying to save yourself from having `substring(col1, 78, 14)` twice; if that's the case, try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        col1,
        SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 5) AS COL2,
        SUBSTRING(col1, 38, 5) AS COL3,
        SUBSTRING(col1, 78, 14) AS COL4
    FROM
        #tempgb
)
SELECT
    *,
    usr.Udf_OverPunch(col4) AS Overpunch
FROM
    CTE;
```

If you don't care if you have `substring(col1, 78, 14)` twice, just send it directly and save yourself the CTE:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 5) AS COL2,
    SUBSTRING(col1, 38, 5) AS COL3,
    SUBSTRING(col1, 78, 14) AS COL4,
    usr.Udf_OverPunch(SUBSTRING(col1, 78, 14)) AS Overpunch
FROM
    #tempgb
```